# Can the mass of a SUSY particle depend on the process it participates in?

Tags: particle-physics, supersymmetry, elementary-particles

I believe that mass is property of every particle,as well as spin etc.Now I'm interested in SUSY particles in cMSSM model.Can it be,that mass of a SUSY particle (at one point in five parameter space) depend on process it is participating in,or parents particles? I doubt it.

Comment: As long as one picks a fixed definition of the mass - there are various different "types of masses" like the running mass at some scale, and so on - then it is unique for a particular particle. There's lot of freedom in SUSY and other BSM models and if masses of everything were also process-dependent, it would be fuzzy, indeed.